# Comparing array elements and trying to add dissimilar elements to other array not working?

Tags: c

i am trying to compare array elements and idea is to collect all dissimilar element to other temp[] array. I think it is going somewhere wrong ...unable to understand...please help me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 30

int my_arr[SIZE] = {10,20,45,63,89,20,15,12,89,24,12,10,89,25,64,39,37,64,95,
                  27,23,58,97,23,18,56,94,76,32,11                                                      
                   };


int main()
{

   int i,j,temp_arr[100];



  for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
  {
     for(j=0+i; j<SIZE; j++)
     {
        if(*(my_arr+i)!=*(my_arr+j))

              *(my_arr+i) = temp_arr[i];

     }

      }
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes that's right ...but not getting where it is going wrong...i am new to C...i sure some one is going to find it out here...thanks

Comment: `temp_arr` is not initialized, but you're copying something out of it.  This is bad!  You might want to reverse the assignment; you also need to index `temp_arr` separately from both `i` and `j`, so you need an extra index `k` to record where you are in `temp_arr`.

Comment: thanks Jonathan...you are right i need to reverse the assignment..thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
*(my_arr+i) = temp_arr[i];
```

`temp_arr[j]` is not initialized and you are assigning it to `my_arr[i]`. You description sounds like you want:

```
temp_arr[i] = *(my_arr+i);
```

But then you will end up having `holes` in the `temp_arr`. So perhaps you need another index for counting items in the `temp_arr`.

Something like:

```
int tmp_cnt = 0;
for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++) {
     for(j=0+i; j<SIZE; j++) {
        if(*(my_arr+i)!=*(my_arr+j))
              temp_arr[tmp_cnt++] = *(my_arr+i);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Pretty much what I commented — but you answered.

Comment: yes, this is the same as you comment, thanks

Comment: got it guys actually i was wrong trying to copy from temp_arr[], actually i should be copying from my_arr[] to temp_arr[]...It is solved as follows
           temp_arr[i] = *(my_arr+i);

Comment: please guide me how to print in line code here

Comment: @studyembedded, you also need a temp_arr index (like the above) or initialize the elements in temp_arr.

Comment: @perreal thanks for this example, this solved my second questions as well. To print temp_arr i was not getting number of elements there ...this will solve it...thanks